# Is it possible to schedule approving and blocking users (user status) triggered for example by date?

Tags: 8, users

On D8, any recommendation on approving and blocking user status (active or blocked) by schedule (for example triggered by some dates)? Use case e.g. users as members on subscription, will require renewal for e.g. annually. No payments/commerce involved.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a cron job and you can schedule it with [Job Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/job_scheduler).

Simple example:

> ```
> // Declare scheduler.
>
>   function example_cron_job_scheduler_info() {
>     $schedulers = [];
>     $schedulers['example_unpublish'] = [
>       'worker callback' => 'example_unpublish_nodes',
>     ];
>     return $schedulers;
>   }
>
> // Add a job.
>
>   $job = [
>     'name' => 'example_unpublish',
>     'type' => 'story',
>     'id' => 12, // must be unique
>     'period' => 3600, // in seconds, so its set to 60 min / 1 hour
>     'periodic' => TRUE, // set to false if you want to just run once.
>   ];
>   $service = \Drupal::service('job_scheduler.manager');
>   $service->set($job);
>
> // Work off a job.
>
>   function example_unpublish_nodes(\Drupal\job_scheduler\Entity\JobSchedule $job) {
>     // Do stuff.
>   }
> ```

There is more examples & info in the [READ.ME](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/job_scheduler/-/blob/8.x-3.x/README.txt), so read it.